# Creating interactive plots in tikz with pop-ups

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ocg

I'm trying to create a 2-d plot in LaTeX. I am facing two issues:

1. I am using the `ocg` package to make the plots appear/disappear by clicking on the legend. It *partially* works as the markers in the plots are not disappearing. Any idea why this would be happening?
2. I want to make the graphs more descriptive, so clicking on certain location can give them more information. For example, in the current code, if I take my mouse over "A", it gives a description about it using pdftooltips. I'm using the coordinate location of "A" in the given case but can I get a similar explanation for the plots themselves, let's say if I point anywhere on the plot with square markers, it should explain it.

Here is a working examples for what I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,calc,shadows,chains,ocgx,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5,samples=10}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={scale=8}}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\newcommand*\rfrac[2]{{}^{#1}\!/_{#2}}
\newcommand*{\Peak}{18}
% The data files, written on the first run.
\begin{filecontents}{in1.data}
Granularity      Speedup
16      0.71
32      0.72
64      0.75
128     0.80
256     0.89
512     1.08
1024    1.44
2048    2.10
4096    3.23
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{in2.data}
Granularity      Speedup
16      0.71
32      0.73
64      0.75
128     0.80
256     0.90
512     1.10
1024    1.50
2048    2.28
4096 3.80
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=2}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
height=10cm, width=20cm,
axis lines=left,
xlabel={Granularity (Bytes)},
ylabel= {Speedup},
xmin=8,
xmax=8192,
xtick={16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192},
xticklabels={16,,,128,,,1K,,,8K,},
ymin=0.1,
ymax=100,
ytick={0.1,1,10,100},
yticklabels={0.1,1,10,100},
ymajorgrids,
legend entries={\switchocg{actual}{LogCA},\switchocg{A}{$A_{10x}$}},
legend columns=-1,
legend style={at={(0.8,-0.4)},font=\Huge},
xticklabel style={
rotate=37,},
]
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=actual,status=visible}]
\addplot  [black,solid,very thick] table {in1.data};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A,status=visible}]
\addplot  [mark=square] table {in2.data};
\end{scope}

\node(source1) at (axis cs:0,\Peak){};
\node(destination1) at (axis cs:67108864,\Peak){};
\draw[-,very thick,red](source1)--(destination1);

\node[black,above] (c) at (axis cs:16,\Peak){A};
\draw (c) node {\pdftooltip{\rule{0pt}{5pt}\rule{5pt}{0pt}}{Hint: Peak Acceleration}};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This works with more recent versions of `pgfplots`. You have two solutions: (1) upgrade to a decent version of `pgfplots` or (2) add `clip marker paths` to the `axis` (this feature causes special drawing layers for markers which confuses OCG).
2. You may want to take a look at the `clickable` library shipped with `pgfplots`, it allows to add interactive plots using builtin methods. Its key features are

   - a click somewhere shows a popup with the coordinates below the mouse cursor
   - a click on a coordinate show customizable meta data about the associated data point (this is the closest offered inbuilt feature for "meta data of the plot)
   - drag and drop shows the start and end points *and* the slope of a line between these two

Here is the result with `clickable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,calc,shadows,chains,ocgx,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5,samples=10}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={scale=8}}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\newcommand*\rfrac[2]{{}^{#1}\!/_{#2}}
\newcommand*{\Peak}{18}
% The data files, written on the first run.
\begin{filecontents}{in1.data}
Granularity      Speedup
16      0.71
32      0.72
64      0.75
128     0.80
256     0.89
512     1.08
1024    1.44
2048    2.10
4096    3.23
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{in2.data}
Granularity      Speedup
16      0.71
32      0.73
64      0.75
128     0.80
256     0.90
512     1.10
1024    1.50
2048    2.28
4096 3.80
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=2}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
height=10cm, width=20cm,
axis lines=left,
xlabel={Granularity (Bytes)},
ylabel= {Speedup},
xmin=8,
xmax=8192,
xtick={16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192},
xticklabels={16,,,128,,,1K,,,8K,},
ymin=0.1,
ymax=100,
ytick={0.1,1,10,100},
yticklabels={0.1,1,10,100},
ymajorgrids,
legend entries={\switchocg{actual}{LogCA},\switchocg{A}{$A_{10x}$}},
legend columns=-1,
legend style={at={(0.8,-0.4)},font=\Huge},
xticklabel style={
rotate=37,},
]
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=actual,status=visible}]
\addplot  [black,solid,very thick,
    clickable coords={in1 (xy)}] table {in1.data};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A,status=visible}]
\addplot  [mark=square,
    clickable coords={in2 (xy)}] table {in2.data};
\end{scope}

\node(source1) at (axis cs:0,\Peak){};
\node(destination1) at (axis cs:67108864,\Peak){};
\draw[-,very thick,red](source1)--(destination1);

\node[black,above] (c) at (axis cs:16,\Peak){A};
\draw (c) node {\pdftooltip{\rule{0pt}{5pt}\rule{5pt}{0pt}}{Hint: Peak Acceleration}};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Click on a datapoint of `in2.dat` expands the argument `clickable coords={in2 (xy)}`:

[image]

Same for `in1.dat` -- but more tricky since it has no markers:

[image]

Click somewhere into the axis:

[image]

Drag and drop shows the slope:

[image]

The `clickable` lib has special runtime requirements as it requires the LaTeX packages `insdljs` and `eforms`, and I believe that these libraries became nonfree at some time in the past. I still have some old free versions of these libraries on my system and I admit that I am unsure if they are still part of TeX distributions.